# How to implement Tuner dial or horizontal wheel view in android

Tags: android, xml, scroll

How to implement Tuner dial or horizontal wheel view in android..
Like this: http://hmonitoring.comuf.com/screen568x568.jpeg

Comment: Make a custom seekbar

Comment: Create your own custom view

Answer (score 0):

For such purpose either you need to create custom view or you can take a look at [here](https://github.com/ai212983/android-spinnerwheel), which might solve your issue or you can further search on Horizontal Wheel View for android on Google.